# refresh rand() in php if result matches databse entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains numbers relating to barcodes that identify each row. The barcode column is unique and the primary key.

Upon registering at my site I want a random string of numbers to be generated and stored in the barcode field. Currectly I am using this Command to generate the string >

```
$barcode = mt_rand(100000, 999999).mt_rand(100000, 999999);
```

Then I am using this to check if the entry exists >

```
$resultbarcode = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE barcode='$barcode'") or die($mysqli->error());
```

Then using an If statement >

```
if ( $resultbarcode->num_rows > 0 ) {


}
```

Im checking if rows returned is more than 0. If so I want to refresh the $barcode variable until there is no result.

Can this be done like this or should I have the $barcode in a seperate .php doc and call it into this one?

Comment: you can do like this but use `prepared statements`

Answer (score 3):

Don't torment your poor database spamming queries to see if the barcode you just created already exists into an iteration. Fetch all the existing barcodes with a single query into an array and then check your brand new barcode over it using the [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). It will be faster... and healthier:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT barcode FROM users") or die($mysqli->error());
$barcodes = $mysqli->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

do 
{
    $barcode = mt_rand(100000, 999999).mt_rand(100000, 999999);
}
while (in_array($barcode, $barcodes));
```

Alternatively, since on database side your users should be associated to a unique ID, find an algorithm that produces a unique barcode based on that value.

Comment: This may or may not be the efficient approach. If there are a billion existing barcodes but a trillion possibilities, you'll be overwhelming the server to prevent a 1/1000th chance of a collision.

Comment: This is why I recommented to find a way to create the barcodes directly from ids. I don't know if it's feasible, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved with a `do-while` loop: [do-while documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

```
do {
    $barcode = mt_rand(100000, 999999).mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $resultbarcode = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE barcode='$barcode'") or die($mysqli->error());
} while ( $resultbarcode->num_rows > 0);

//$barcode will be an unique barcode now.
```

Compared to a normal `while` loop, the `do-while` loop will execute the first iteration first and evaluate the condition afterwards.

Comment: I went with this in the end. I did wonder about overloading the server as Tom pointed out below, but with it only being run once per user life i.e only at registration, and the amount of users im expecting im not to worried.